# Using URL with double {} in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make this link working in laravel :

```
 <a href="/single-article/{{$post->post_id}}/@lang('messages.slaglan')">
```

using `{{ url('/') }}`

How can i make this without error ?

Comment: you want to replace the whole href by url function?

Comment: Yes , that's it

Comment: I cant see what's the problem with that?

Comment: If I write this  {{ url('/single-article/{{$post->post_id}}/@lang('messages.slaglan')') }}
It's giving me errors because of using () double times and also because of using this {{}} double time

Comment: How can i do that ?  becuase not using Url function make me went to the wrong url

Comment: Can you update your question with a dump of your posts object, your routes and your lang file? will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named routes please. 
Assuming you have something like this

```
Route::get('/single-article/{id}/{slaglan}', array(
    'as' => 'get-this-article',
    'uses' => 'SomeController@action'
));

<a href="{{URL::route('get-this-article', [$id, $slaglan] )}}">Visit</a>
```